# What is the .NET 4.5 Windows Store App equivalent of AsyncOperationManager?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.5, windows-store-apps

Currently digging into developing a Windows Store App for my new Surface device, I am trying to port a small application from .NET 2.0 WinForms.

I am using the [`AsyncOperationManager` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperationmanager.aspx) to [implementing a component that supports the event-based asynchronous pattern](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz33kx67.aspx). It seems that this class is not supported for use in a Windows Store App.

Probably I have to rewrite the app/class from ground up with those new [asynchronous functions in .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156548.aspx), still there might be an easier way to proceed.

**Therefore my question is:**

Is there a direct replacement in .NET 4.5 Windows Store Apps for the `AsyncOperationManager` class?

Comment: Portability to Windows Store is low in general, it is zero for Winforms apps.  Use the Task<> class and the async/await keywords.

Comment: Ironically enough, I was able to use the `AsyncOperationManager` code successfully with Mono Mac, Mono Touch and Mono Droid to write iPhone, Mac and Android applications with ease. The only thing I struggle with is Windows App Store. Microsoft is less compatible to itself than external vendors. m(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be one of those areas where you will end up rewriting this code using the new framework.  MS warned that there would be these situations and they were not lying.  I have a similar project that I am trying to port over and there have been quite a few situations where I have had to rewrite code.  I am going to dig into this more, but my first 30 minutes of research have not turned up anything hopeful.